# Issue with Uploading File to Amazon S3 Bucket: File Saved as Blank

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I'm facing an issue when trying to upload a PDF file to an S3 bucket using a Single Page Application (SPA) hosted on CloudFront. The setup involves a .NET C# API deployed on Lambda, with routes set in API Gateway for handling the upload process. Additionally, the SPA is built using Angular and hosted on an S3 bucket.

When attempting to upload the PDF file locally with API Gateway routes, the process completes successfully. However, after building and publishing the SPA on CloudFront, the uploaded PDF file is saved as blank.

Can anyone help me with this issue?
This problem is in CloudFront or in Angular build?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.